# how to add enfold theme shortcode to my wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a new theme for a site which is using endfold at the moment 
Now, i have a problem with previous posts that have used enfold's shortcode and my theme doesn't support them how can I add enfold's shortcode to my theme

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes in Wordpress are defined likes this:

```
    //[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

You have to find the defined shortcut in the endfold theme files (just grep for the shortcode alias) and reimplement this code on your theme.

Comment: thanks, mr.void But I knew how to add a shortcode for a wordpress theme but endfold has a special structure for itself and this makes me confuse

Comment: I think they use the WP-Shortcode API, so there must a defining of these:
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );